# is it possible to combine these two functions into one?

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions that are basically identical.  The first function gets passed a mouse event where event.target is the input type='checkbox'  the second function gets passed the input type='checkbox'  is there a way to rewrite these into one function?

```
function crewChecked(event){                
    if(event.target.checked){
        names.push(event.target.value)
    }else{
        for(let i = 0; i < names.length;i++){
            if(names[i] == event.target.value){
                names = names.filter((name, index) => index !== i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(names.length==0){
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = "Select Crew"
    }else{
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = names.length + " crew"
    }
}


function crewChecked2(crewCheckbox){
    if(crewCheckbox.checked){
        names.push(crewCheckbox.value)
    }else{
        for(let i = 0; i < names.length;i++){
            if(names[i] == crewCheckbox.value){
                names = names.filter((name, index) => index !== i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(names.length==0){
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = "Select Crew"
    }else{
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = names.length + " crew"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you try doing a single function with the main code that takes the checkbox input as parameter and the second function with the event calls the first one with the event.target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part of these two functions that differ are how you get the reference to the checkbox. So if you figure out how to get that checkbox in both cases, you're golden.

Something like:

```
function crewChecked(eventOrCheckbox){          
      
    // Added
    const checkbox = eventOrCheckbox.target || eventOrCheckbox

    if(checkbox.checked){
        names.push(checkbox.value)
    }else{
        for(let i = 0; i < names.length;i++){
            if(names[i] == checkbox.value){
                names = names.filter((name, index) => index !== i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(names.length==0){
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = "Select Crew"
    }else{
        document.getElementById('dropdownCrewButton').innerText = names.length + " crew"
    }
}
```

This line checks for a `target` property on the `eventOrCheckbox` argument. If there is one, then it's an event and the checkbox should be saved to `checkbox`. If there isn't, then assume this argument *is* the checkbox and continue on.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is whether you test `event.target.checked` and `event.target.value` or `crewCheckbox.checked` and `crewCheckbox.value`. `crewChecked` can call `crewChecked2`, passing `event.target` as the argument.

```
function crewChecked(event) {
    crewChecked2(event.target);
}
```